# What is cvtres.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, csc

When I'm using aspnet_compiler.exe to pre-compile my website, I see a `cvtres.exe` process along with `csc.exe`. I'm assuming this is part of the .NET compilation process, and would also show when compiling my .NET assemblies. **What is `cvtres.exe` and what does it do?**

Comment: Incredibly obscure, cvtres dates from the stone age and is not part of the normal .NET build chain.  How old is this web site project?  Any chance it got started as ASP (without .NET)?  What do the resource files look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows Resource to Object Converter (CvtRes.exe) (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hs24szh9.aspx))

As to what it does, well... I guess that it converts Resources to Objects.

**Edit:** As Scott says,

> to be more specific, it is part of the C++ toolchain to turn resource
>   files (.res) in to compiled objects that can be linked using the
>   linker.

I was looking for something official that explains it, but the best I could find is [an old support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230332) that mentions it. Hope it helps!

Comment: to be more specific, it is part of the C++ toolchain to turn resource files (`.res`) in to compiled objects that can be linked using the linker.

Comment: thanks Scott, that does help explain it a little better. I was hoping to find something from Microsoft that explains it's use but it seems to be *way* down in the weeds, and although it's referenced a lot on MSDN, I couldn't find anything specific that explains it any better than that.